# Export ReactNative screen/view to a PDF

Tags: react-native

I have ReactNative app. Could I save app's main screen/view in PDF or in any other printable file format?

Answer (score 3):

@React Bala,

Use **react-native-view-shot** component.

> `https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot`

```
import RNViewShot from "react-native-view-shot";

RNViewShot.takeSnapshot(viewRef, {
  format: "jpeg",
  quality: 0.8
})
.then(
  uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
  error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
);
```

You got image `URI`
After

> https://github.com/Anyline/react-native-image-to-pdf

use this component for convert image to pdf...

Comment: Thank you but error is displaying(Im using android tab) [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeHtmlToPdf.default.convert')]